# Edit permissions for Django Details View for api calls

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am very new to django and currently trying to generate api calls to localhost:8000/stateapi/id where id is an id for a single "State" object in a json (like 1, 2, etc).
It is using token authentication by passing a username and password to the "get-token" endpoint and then using that token for calls to the stateapi endpoint.

I mostly followed this tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-rest-api-with-django-a-test-driven-approach-part-2
and keep getting a "detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."

Here are the views where CreateView handles the "localhost:8000/stateapi" endpoint and DetailsView handles the localhost:8000/stateapi/id endpoint.

```
class CreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):                   
    queryset = State.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StateSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,IsOwner)                       
                                                                       
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """Save the post data when creating a new State."""
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)                   
                                                                   
class DetailsView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):        
    """This class handles the http GET, PUT and DELETE requests."""

    queryset = State.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StateSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,IsOwner)
```

I can't seem to figure out why the authenticated user has permission to access information from CreateView but not DetailsView.

Here is the permissions code:

```
class IsOwner(BasePermission):
"""Custom permission class to allow only bucketlist owners to edit them."""

def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    # Our problem is that we do not have a owner property for the object
    """Return True if permission is granted to the bucketlist owner."""
    return obj.owner == request.user
```

Upon testing what happens when DetailsView is called, i've found that obj.owner is "None" when DetailsView is called and obj.owner is correctly equal to request.user whenever CreateView is called which would explain why the authenticated user can make get requests to the endpoint without an id while it cannot for the endpoint with an id.

Are there an suggestions as to how I could either:

- a) make sure obj has the correct "owner" property (something that CreateView is doing but DetailsView is not)
- b) change my permissions in some way
- c) something else I cannot think of.

Thanks!

> Can you share your State model and StateSerializer – Iain Shelvington Jun 18 at 3:26

State Model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Create your models here.
# 1 is /, 2 is -, 3 is (, 4 is ), 5 is .
class State(models.Model):
    STATE                                                   = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True)
    Team_Contact                                            = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    CONTACT_INFORMATION                                     = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    LEGISLATION1EXECUTIVE_ORDER                             = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    TESTING                                                 = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    TESTING1DEPLOYMENT_REQUIREMENTS_3SELF_CERTIFICATION4    = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    PRE2EMPTION                                             = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    owner                                                   = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='statelists', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)                                                  
    OVERSIGHT_DEPARTMENT                                    = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    INFRASTRUCTURE_DEVELOPMENTS                             = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    CRASHES1SAFETY_INCIDENTS                                = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    DATA1PRIVACY_CONCERNS                                   = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    PUBLIC_EDUCATION_FOR_AVS                                = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    LIABILITY1INSURANCE_REQUIREMENTS                        = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    HEALTH1EQUITY_CONCERNS                                  = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    MISC5                                                   = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a human readable representation of the model instance."""
        return "{}".format(self.STATE)
    
    # This receiver handles token creation immediately a new user is created.
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Serializers:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import State
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class StateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer to map the Model instance into JSON format."""

    # understand exactly what this line does
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username') 

    class Meta:
        """Meta class to map serializer's fields with the model fields."""
        model = State
        fields = ('id','STATE','Team_Contact','CONTACT_INFORMATION','LEGISLATION1EXECUTIVE_ORDER','TESTING',
        'TESTING1DEPLOYMENT_REQUIREMENTS_3SELF_CERTIFICATION4','PRE2EMPTION','OVERSIGHT_DEPARTMENT','INFRASTRUCTURE_DEVELOPMENTS',
        'CRASHES1SAFETY_INCIDENTS','DATA1PRIVACY_CONCERNS','PUBLIC_EDUCATION_FOR_AVS','LIABILITY1INSURANCE_REQUIREMENTS',
        'HEALTH1EQUITY_CONCERNS','MISC5', 'owner')

        read_only_fields = ('STATE', 'Team_Contact','CONTACT_INFORMATION')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A user serializer to aid in authentication and authorization."""

    states = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=State.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        """Map this serializer to the default django user model."""
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'states')
```

Comment: Can you share your `State` model and `StateSerializer`

Comment: Sure! I will share it

Comment: It might be because the serializer for owner has `source=owner.username` not sure this is necessary. I'd imagine this is a string and not the user name object you're expecting.

Comment: I deleted it but the permission was still denied for stateapi/1 :(

Answer (score 0):

All things here seem to be normal. I think the problem comes from other parts of your code? Or your checked object actually doesn't have any owner linked to it?

Comment: Any idea how I would make sure my checked object has an owner linked to it? I am not sure why CreateView has the proper object owner but DetailsView does not.

Comment: I mean did you really check that your object was saved with a linked owner? I'm imaging a scenario that you just add owner attribute to your object without saving. You can check the records in your database to check it. That's what I think ^^

Comment: What would be your advice on saving an object with a linked owner?